# Generate .beam file for imported module

Tags: erlang

I'm learning erlnag and have a small doubt regarding '.beam' file creation.
For example I have helloworld.erl and top.erl files and helloworld.erl is imported in top.erl.

**top.erl:**

```
-module(top).
-import(helloworld, [start/0]).
-export([main/0]).

main() ->
  io:fwrite("hello\n"),
  start().
```

**helloworld.erl**

```
-module(helloworld).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
  io:fwrite("hello world\n").
```

Then compiling top.erl using "erlc top.erl".Then, it is creating only top.beam file but not creating helloworld.beam file.

But when we see in case of python and java, object files will be generate for the imported file also while compiling importing file.

is this the behavior(i.e not creating .beam file for imported file) of 'erlang' or am i understood wrong?

(or)

Please explain the process to get the '.beam' files for imported one also while running importing module.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

`erlc` only compiles the files you ask it to compile. You can compile all files in the current directory with:

```
erlc *.erl
```

---

You might want to use a tool to build your project. One option that's built-in is [the `make` module](https://erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) (not to be confused with the `make` command line tool). You can run it with:

```
erl -make
```

It looks for a configuration file called `Emakefile` file in the current directory, but if there is none it will just compile all source files in the directory.

Other alternatives are [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/) and [erlang.mk](https://erlang.mk/).

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain the process to get the '.beam' files for imported one
> also while running importing module.

There is none.  Furthermore, no one who writes Erlang uses `-import` for modules because it confuses the reader of your code by obfuscating where in fact the function you called is defined.  Normally, when you call a function using the syntax `start()`, that means the function is defined in the module where it is called, and when a function is defined in another module, you call it with the syntax `helloworld:start()`, which informs the reader of your code that they can examine the `helloworld` module to read the definition of the `start()` function.

> But when we see in case of python and java, object files will be
> generate for the imported file also while compiling importing file.

Erlang's `-import` doesn't work that way.

Comment: I can see the case of using `-import` for a set of global functions which might act like a sort of syntactic sugar for other functions or a set of nested functions. So global_funs:string_transform() could just be referenced as string_transfor() after it's been imported.

Comment: @Samwar, Your use case still has the same problem mentioned.  You can choose to write clear code, or you can choose to write garbled code.